# How to set the criteria result to another pojo class variables in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, criteria

I am fetching data from database using criteria and in criteria i am using groupProperty() and sum().

I want to know that i want to update this result into my another table. The way i know is to set the results from here to another pojo class and then update into another table. But i want to know that is there any other way to do this?If there then please suggest me.

Here is my pojo class ***Post.java***

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Post implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="uid")
private long userId;

@Column(name="value")
private long val;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public long getVal() {
    return val;
}

public void setVal(long val) {
    this.val = val;
}
}
```

Here is my **DAO** class

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Post> getPostList() throws Exception {
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Post.class);
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
    projList.add(Projections.sum("val"));
    projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("userId"));
    cr.setProjection(projList);
    List postList = cr.list();
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return postList;
}
}
```

And here is my another pojo class ***Result.java*** in which i want these two results

```
public class Result {

private long topValue;
private long uid;
public long getTopValue() {
    return topValue;
}
public void setTopValue(long topValue) {
    this.topValue = topValue;
}
public long getUid() {
    return uid;
}
public void setUid(long uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the setResultTransformers method of criteria and add the alias to your add method of ProjectionList, you should get a List of type Result.

```
public List<Result> getResultList() throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Post.class);
        ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
        projList.add(Projections.sum("val"), "topValue");
        projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("userId"), "uid");
        cr.setProjection(projList);
        cr.setResultTransformers(Transformers.aliasToBean(Result.class)
        List postList = cr.list();
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        session.beginTransaction();
        tx.commit();
        return postList;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Now what should i do to insert these values into another table?

Comment: Use the entity annotation for your result class as you used for post class. Then you have to persist the result of the getResultList mehtod with the hibernate persistence service.

Comment: i want to update a table after the result is set to Result class with value where id is uid but i dont know how to do it please suggest me

Comment: Sorry couldn't help there, better create another question.